# Backbone view to re-render if any other view gets rendered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a TooltipView that pops up whenever an element with class `.tooltip` is moused-over and takes the content of that elements `data-tooltip` attribute and displays it in the tooltip.
I bind the events for TooltipView in it's initialise function but the problem is if another view is dynamically created, or re-rendered then TooltipView doesn't know about it.

```
var tooltipView =  Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#tooltip-container',

    initialize: function() {
        $('.tooltip').on('mouseover', function() {
             ....
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can manually trigger events from each of the views when they're rendered but is there away to do it just from within TooltipView?
I'd like TooltipView to listen for ANY view to render and then re-render itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe attaching events to higher DOM level would work for you:

```
initialize: function() {
    $('body').on('mouseover', '.tooltip', function() {
         ....
    }
}
```

Don't forget to unbind it later though

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, can you explain how? Why should I unbind it later?